# Vue 3: Module not found: Error: path argument is not string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am having vue application inside static JS app and in vuejs's main.js file I am having 3 lines of code:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import componentMap from './componentMap'
createApp(componentMap['vue-home-page']).mount("#vueContainer")
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <h1> VUE Starter Kit </h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

and I am getting error on second line i.e. `import App from './App.vue'`
where it says
**Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string**

componentMap.js:

```
import App from '.App.vue';
const componentMap = {'vue-home-page': App}
export default componentMap
```

vue-page.hbs:

```
<div id='vueContainer'><vue-home-page /></div>
```

Project Structure:

```
src
    hbs-app
        page
            index.hbs
            landing-page.hbs
            vue-page.hbs                
    vue-app
        main.js
        App.vue
        componentMap.js
```

Comment: it should be `createApp(App).mount("#vueContainer")` the mount argument should be a string ""

Comment: Yes there are quotes already, as I manually typed this question that's why I missed it.
But that is not problem here. Application is not able to read '.vue' files. It throws error that ** path argument is not string**

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No not using typescript

Comment: please share the `App.vue` file and the project structure

Comment: added App.vue file